# Create a Form and Reuse Code

Tags: php

I have a current application in PHP and I've finished the application using procedural way of coding in PHP. I want to convert it into OOP way.

I wish to have some basic example of a better approach creating forms and using the same code again in other forms I will create using OOP pattern.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is off-topic; principally by being far too broad and not practically answerable in the SO format. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your data from your HTML form to this file

```
Class Form
    {
      function __construct()
      {
        if(isset($_GET['form_register']))
        {
          $this->check_register_details();
        }

        if(isset($_GET['form_login']))
        {
          $this->check_login_details();
        }

      }

      function check_register_details()
      {
        //do something
      }


  function check_login_details()
  {
    //do something
  }

  function insert_into_db()
  {
   //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir @Lim Guang Jian Im really new to OOP how would I use it.

Comment: You should post your existing code so that we can see how we can transform it to OOP

Comment: Sir @Lim Guang Jian its ok now... I found something that would help me implement your code on my forms... thank you sir...

Comment: Code like this is not a good idea in my opinion. After working on your application, you will get one `Form` class that is way too bloated. I recently started using [Symfony Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) which, yes, is more advanced, meaning that you'll automatically use principles that are usually considered good practice

Comment: sir @kingkero could you give a better example. I jsut want to grasp into a better solution. Honestly Im very new to OOP. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kitkay Look at the link that I posted in my previous comment (or [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html)). This will show you a Form Component using build function, fields as classes, etc